# Get one value if None, other if not None?

Tags: python

```
deathdate = None
is_alive = someting(deathdate)
```

if deathdate is not None then is alive is false
if deathdate is None then is alive is true

what is something?

Comment: `is_alive = None != deathdate`??

Comment: @JohnnyMopp, it's the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

You've written out most of what you need in a pseudocode format already. You can build this operation into an if statement.

```
if deathdate == None:
    is_alive = True
else:
    is_alive = False
```

Comment: Absolutly, but i thought that python had a oneliner for this :)

Comment: Seems a bit redundant. How about `is_alive = deathdate == None`? Or, more idiomatically, `is_alive = deathdate is None`

Answer (score 0):

```py
deathdate = None

True if deathdate else False
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
is_alive = deathdate is None
```